# Group elements in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible using XSLT to group items in an XML file?

Input file:

```
<start>

<A>
---data---
</A>

<B>
---data---
</B>

<C>
---data---
</C>

<A>
---data---
</A>

<B>
---data---
</B>

</start>
```

Output should be:

```
<start>

<A>
---data---
</A>

<A>
---data---
</A>

<B>
---data---
</B>

<B>
---data---
</B>

<C>
---data---
</C>

</start>
```

How do I do that using XSL? Or is there any better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it sorting by element name?

Comment: Kinda like that, yes...start is the root node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sample input:

```
<start>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
    <C>3</C>
    <A>4</A>
    <B>5</B>
</start>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="start">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>

                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<start>
  <A>1</A>
  <A>4</A>
  <B>2</B>
  <B>5</B>
  <C>3</C>
</start>
```

Comment: What If the elements contain further keys ? Would the same thing work or does it require any change ?

Comment: This template only sorts elements by their names. It doesn't depend on node's content.

Comment: Thanks mate...one more question, what if the root node contains the schema as well ?? eg. <start xmlns="schema.xml"> ... </start> ... the template match = doesn't seems to allow more quotes ??

Comment: What happens if I change <xsl:template match="start"> to <xsl:template match="*">

Answer (score 0):

Unlike sorting, grouping is not directly supported in XSLT I think

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, try this....

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="start/*">
        <xsl:sort select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Kirill's use of the copy-to is a better approach since it will make an exact copy of the node, including all attributes and children